# Estoy obteniendo todos los datos una colección, pero toma mucho tiempo, ¿ Habrá una manera mas optimizada de hacerlo?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Asi estoy haciendo la consulta,estoy trayendo todo lo que hay en la colección.
¿ Alguna otra manera de hacerlo, que sea mucho más rapido ?

```
     function listProduc(req, res) {
        Producto.find({}, (err, products) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({
              message: "Productos no encontrados"
          });
        }
        if (!products) {
           res.status(404).send({
              message: "Error al buscar productos"
          });
       }
       res.send(products)
    });
```

Agradezco sus respuestas

Comment: y cuanto es ese tiempo?

Comment: 30 segundos para traer 7.000 datos.
Y en total la colección tiene 217.000 datos

Comment: lo único que se me ocurre es que te traigas los datos de forma paginada. Te los traes de 50 en 50 por ejemplo y en algún sitio pones un botón de "cargar más" y te traes los 50 siguientes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado a que estas utilizando mongoose podrías utilizar la paginacion para alivianar la carga de esos datos.

```
npm install mongoose-paginate
```

En tu modelo:

```
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
const productsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...}); productsSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

En tu controlador:

```
Producto.paginate({}, { page: 1, limit: 100 }, function(err, result) {...});
```

Y con esto puedes ir extrayendo pequeños grupos de datos con sólo cambiar el número de página

Puedes leer la doc [aquí](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate/blob/master/README.md)